# How do I mass replace https to http at linux command

Tags: linux, ssl

How do I mass replace https to http at linux command

I used to use this line

```
find . -type f|xargs sed -i 's#\(account[.]\)mywebsite\([.]com\)#\1mynewwebsite\2#g'
```

But now I just want to change all the https to http due to my certificate issue, I want to disable ssl first and rename all the https path to http

I tried to find on the link suggested but it doesn't work

Comment: not very clear what you mean. Do you want to replace `http` with `https` in multiple files?

Comment: @fedorqui I want replace https with http, recursive replace from the current folder on all the files that contain string https into http. and including the sub folder

Comment: @fedorqui I can't find the command for https into http at that page.

Comment: You just have to adapt the command to replace your string instead of the one used in that question.

Comment: @fedorqui I tried but it say sed found no input files.

Comment: Then post the exact your are using, because this doesn't make sense. Try to show some effort if you want to be assisted.